# some html meta tag text in visible on live page

Tags: html, velo

I have designed a website on WIX and now when I view the site live I see some HTML code appearing on the top of the page. like this image
[image]

Can someone tell how to remove / hide this code?

Comment: I don't use Wix but; can you provide the code inside your head? Should be at the beginning of your page. Like this <head>This code...</head>

Comment: It might be a bug or an extension in you browser. Try to open it in incognito. If it still there, send a ticket to support.

Answer (score 0):

In one of the custom code section the HTML was without the start tag "<" which was causing this issue.